# Need to include the parameter in javascript url in htmls

Tags: javascript

I have an requirement where I need to pass the parameter dynamically in script url.

Example:

```
"<" script src="myfile.js" "><"/script>"
```

now I need to pass the timestamp in the src like

```
"<"script src="myfile.js?tm=12345"><"/script">"
```

so whenever the this html load it should always take the new timestamp and pass in to the url.

```
"<"script src="myfile.js?tm=6788"><"/script">"
```

I would really appreciate in case some can help me to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: `myfile.js` is generated at run-time using some server side scripting? if yes, why not get time information at server side itself?

Comment: how are you getting the timestamp in html? there should be a way to get it in js as well, if not then you can set some element value in html to that timestamp and read that value in your js

Comment: & a hint to answer your question, you can use `document.write` or `document.createElement('script')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.setAttribute('src',generateSrc()); // add your logic in generateSrc
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create dinamically your tag with timestamp, you can do it in two different ways: 
By using DOM:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.setAttribute('src',"myfile.js?tm="+(new Date()).getTime()); //(new Date()).getTime() Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(e);
```

By using innerHTML:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML+= '<script src="myfile.js?tm='+(new Date()).getTime()+'"></script>';
```

Here's http://cjihrig.com/blog/passing-arguments-to-external-javascript-files/ a tutorial that explain how to pass and retrive arguments to an external script.